# Compiler skipping foreach() loop during compilation?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I created a method in which i am configuring a networking device via telnet.The problem is that i have multiple values which i am configuring using `foreach()` loop but the compiler is skipping that loop.I am using C# WPF and pattern is MVVM. Here is my code:

```
public ObservableCollection<VLANSPropertyClass> vlan { get; set; }

 public bool VLAN()
        {
            vlan = new ObservableCollection<VLANSPropertyClass>();

            string _command;

            _command = "config t \n";
            WriteAPCommand(_command);

            ReadAPCommand();

            foreach(VLANSPropertyClass v in vlan)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------FOREACH STARTED----------------");
                _command = "vlan " + v.vid + "\n";
                WriteAPCommand(_command);

                ReadAPCommand();

                _command = "name " + v.vname + "\n";
                WriteAPCommand(_command);

                ReadAPCommand();

                _command = "interface " + v.vid + "\n";
                WriteAPCommand(_command);

                ReadAPCommand();

                _command = "ip address " + v.ip + " " + v.mask + "\n";
                WriteAPCommand(_command);

                ReadAPCommand();

                _command="exit\r";
                WriteAPCommand(_command);

                ReadAPCommand();

                _command = "interface " + v.vports + "\n";
                WriteAPCommand(_command);

                ReadAPCommand();

                _command = "switchport access " + v.vid + "\n";
                WriteAPCommand(_command);

                ReadAPCommand();

                _command = "copy runningconfig startupconfig\n";
                WriteAPCommand(_command);

                ReadAPCommand();

            }
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------FOREACH COMPLETED----------------");
            return true;

        }
```

VLANSProperty class is:

```
public class VLANSPropertyClass
    {
        public string vname { get; set; }

        public int S_No { get; set; }

        public string vid { get; set; }

        public string ip { get; set; }

        public string mask { get; set; }

        public string vports { get; set; }
    }
```

bool Vlan() function is present in `Model` and it is calling from `ViewModel`.Can anyone tell me why my code is not executing correctly.

Comment: You are creating an *empty* collection by `vlan = new ObservableCollection<VLANSPropertyClass>()`. Then you iterate over that collection. What else than zero loop cycles do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new `ObservableCollection<VLANSPropertyClass>()`, but it's empty. Therefore when you iterate over it, you never end up in the body of the loop. You need to *populate* your collection somewhere, before it's useful to iterate over it. (It's possible that you're expecting `ReadAPCommand` to populate it, but you haven't told us anything about that.)

Think about where you're expecting the data to come from, and how you expect it to get into your collection.

You should also consider your property and method names carefully - currently neither of them follow normal .NET conventions, and your `VLAN` method doesn't describe what it's meant to *do* at all.

Comment: ReadAPCommand() is reading data from device its definition is as follos:

Comment: `public string ReadAPCommand()
        {
            _telnetData = new byte[1024];
            _recvBytes = _networkstream.Read(_telnetData, 0, _telnetData.Length);
            _stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_telnetData, 0, _recvBytes);
            Console.WriteLine(_stringData);
            return _stringData;
        }`

Comment: @CodeSniper: So the fact that you're *ignoring the result* of `ReadAPCommand` every time you call it is pretty alarming itself... as is the fact that you're just reading whatever data happens to be available at the time (whether that's a whole response or not), and doing so presumably in the UI thread. How do you expect any of this to populate your collection?

Comment: So what should i need to change ?

Comment: @CodeSniper: Well you've still not given any indication of how you expect the collection to be populated. That's what you really need to think about to start with. You should also work out what you want to do with the return value of `ReadAPCommand`, and probably consider moving all this work away from the UI thread.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet..I want to write all the values present in `ObservableCollection` to device by using WriteAPCommand() method and then read it using ReadAPCommand() method.

Comment: @CodeSniper: You seem to have missed my point. Your collection is *empty*. There are no values in it. You're not populating it anywhere. You need to fix that.

Comment: I didnt miss your point .i am getting confuse little bit i mean how and where to populate values please guide me little bit !

Comment: @CodeSniper: I don't see how we can tell you - we've no idea how you *want* to populate the collection. That's for you to work out! If the point of your loop was to populate the collection, then you don't want to iterate over the *existing* values in it, because there aren't any - instead, you potentially want to keep reading from the connection and populating the collection until the connection is closed. (Again, potentially in a different thread or using asynchronous IO.) But basically you need to take a step back - the problem isn't with the compiler.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55762/discussion-between-codesniper-and-jon-skeet).