# How to populate values in ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I'm working on networking based application using C# WPF. The aim of the application is to configure a networking device via telnet commands running on backend.

The problem where I stuck is that there are multiple values displayed in datagrid which are added by the user, now I want to iterate through all the values and configure my device. I used `ObservableCollection` to hold the values present in a datagrid but in a foreach loop I'm unable to iterate through all the values and populate them because I think the problem is my `ObservableCollection` is empty. Kindly tell me the way in which I can populate my data.

Here is my code:

```
 public ObservableCollection<VLANSPropertyClass> vlan { get; set; }

 public bool VLAN()
        {
            vlan = new ObservableCollection<VLANSPropertyClass>();

            string _command;

            _command = "config t \n";
            WriteAPCommand(_command);

            ReadAPCommand();

            foreach(VLANSPropertyClass v in vlan)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------FOREACH STARTED----------------");
                _command = "vlan " + v.vid + "\n";
                WriteAPCommand(_command);

                ReadAPCommand();

                _command = "name " + v.vname + "\n";
                WriteAPCommand(_command);

                ReadAPCommand();

                _command = "interface " + v.vid + "\n";
                WriteAPCommand(_command);

                ReadAPCommand();

                _command = "ip address " + v.ip + " " + v.mask + "\n";
                WriteAPCommand(_command);

                ReadAPCommand();

                _command="exit\r";
                WriteAPCommand(_command);

                ReadAPCommand();

                _command = "interface " + v.vports + "\n";
                WriteAPCommand(_command);

                ReadAPCommand();

                _command = "switchport access " + v.vid + "\n";
                WriteAPCommand(_command);

                ReadAPCommand();

                _command = "copy runningconfig startupconfig\n";
                WriteAPCommand(_command);

                ReadAPCommand();

            }
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------FOREACH COMPLETED----------------");
            return true;

        }
```

VLANSProperty class is:

```
public class VLANSPropertyClass
{
    public string vname { get; set; }

    public int S_No { get; set; }

    public string vid { get; set; }

    public string ip { get; set; }

    public string mask { get; set; }

    public string vports { get; set; }
}
```

Read and Write Method is :

```
 public  void WriteAPCommand(string _apCommand)
        {
            _telnetData = new byte[1024];
            _telnetData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_apCommand);
            _networkstream.Write(_telnetData, 0, _telnetData.Length);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }

 public string ReadAPCommand()
        {
            _telnetData = new byte[1024];
            _recvBytes = _networkstream.Read(_telnetData, 0, _telnetData.Length);
            _stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_telnetData, 0, _recvBytes);
            Console.WriteLine(_stringData);
            return _stringData;
        }
```

Comment: You are never adding anything to your `vlan` collection.

Comment: Probably related [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259257/compiler-skipping-foreach-loop-during-compilation) and [Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55762/discussion-between-codesniper-and-jon-skeet)

Answer (score 0):

You need to populate your collection with data before you can iterate it and do anything with the item values. How you populate your collection and how you fetch your data is completely up to you. We don't know any of those details, but in general, you would do something like this:

```
vlan = new ObservableCollection<VLANSPropertyClass>();
VLANSPropertyClass item = new VLANSPropertyClass("fill", "with", "valid", "values");
vlan.Add(item);
```

Or, if you access your data from an external source:

```
foreach (VLANSPropertyClass item in SomeDataAccessMethodThatReturnsACollection)
{
    vlan.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: According to your 2nd option..my property `vlan` is in viewmodel but I am accessing it in model with class name but I am unable to access it .That `vlan` is bind to my datagrid if I am able to access it I am able to populate my data .Tell me the way so that I can access `vlan` property from model?

Comment: What are you referring to as your model?

Comment: Model is where I have implemented my business logic but my vlan property implemented in my viewmodel that is the reason that I am facing null reference exception if I am able to access vlan property in ViewModel than I can populate data !

Comment: If your `vlan` property is in the view model, then you should fill it *in the view model*. There is no discussion on this matter. You should not be trying to access this property from any business classes. You *can* use business (data type) classes to fill the collection, or to display in the UI, but you use them *in the view model*, not the other way around. Either way, this question is starting to drag on now. You need to learn how to program *before* you use this website, not *while* you use it. You seem to be missing too much basic development knowledge for me to help you further.

Comment: @Sheridan..Yes I am pretty new to programming I am still learning but unfortunately due to the sudden quit of my team lead whole responsibility of developing application is come up in my hands that is the reason I am facing some problems ...got it!!